# C#: Subclass List<Something>?

Tags: c#, interface, subclass

I have a class `EqualCondition` which implements my own interface `ICondition`, which has only one method: `SatisfiedBy(Something)`.

```
public class EqualCondition : ICondition {
    private Something m_Something;

    public HelloCondition(Something something) {
        m_Something = something;
    }

    // Magic!!!
    public bool SatisfiedBy(Something something) {
        return something == m_Something;
    }
}
```

So `ICondition` is very simple to implement. Now I'm trying to create a `CombinationCondition` which also implements it. The idea is that `CombinationCondition` which will contain a list of `ICondition`s which will determine whether `SatisfiedBy` will be successful or not.

My first thought was to make `CombinationCondition` implement `IList<Something>` but I quickly realized that I was only duplicating `List<Something>`. So why not just subclass it?

That idea sounded fine until I started thinking again about how to implement `SatisfiedBy` if I just subclassed `List<Something>`.  I need to do:

```
return innerList.All(x => x.SatisfiedBy(something))
```

But how do I access the inner list?

Comment: @blahblah can't you just go this.All(x => x.SatisfiedBy(something)), since this is a List<Something>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, for the use case you're showing, I would just make this implement `IEnumerable<Condition>`.  You could then just implement the GetEnumerator by calling the (internal, encapsulated) `List<Condition>`'s method.

Potentially, `ICollection<Condition>` may make more sense (so you can add conditions at runtime), but only if you need that capability.  Implementing `IList<T>` seems like overkill in this situation, for the use cases I'd see with this.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have posted, I would just have `CombinationCondition` contain (encapsulate) a `List<Something>`. No need for the outside world to know it is a list unless absolutely necessary.

**Edit 1:**

```
public class CombinationCondition : ICondition {
private List<ICondition> list;

public CombinationCondition(List<ICondition> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

// if you need it
public void AddCondition( ICondition condition ){
    list.Add( condition );
}

// Still Magic!!!
public bool SatisfiedBy(Something something) {
    return list.Any( x => x.SatisfiedBy( something ) );
}
```

}

**Edit 2:**
You might also consider renaming `CombinationCondition` to `CompoundCondition`...makes more sense, at least to me :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I 100% understand what you are trying to do, but would this solve your need?

```
public interface ICondition<T>
{
   bool SatisfiedBy(T something);
}
```

That way, you can just implement it for any generic type you need

Comment: no he doesn't ... at least not based on the information provided in the question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be a property of type IList<ICondition> called maybe "Conditions".

You don't need to access the inner list - you could access your class "itself".

However, prefer sublassing from ICollection<T>.